# How do I change a value in "OnInspectorGUI()" void so that I can get it in another script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-editor, unity3d-editor

It's full code, but u do not really nead it full. I need to access varibles in the "Update" at least. I do not know how to change original variables in that void, because they just cannot be changed. There are some notes writen.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Unity.Netcode;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditor.TerrainTools;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerNetwork : NetworkBehaviour
{
    private readonly NetworkVariable<PlayerNetworkData> _netState = new(writePerm: NetworkVariableWritePermission.Owner);
    private Vector3 _vel;
    private float _rotVel;
    [SerializeField] private float _cheapInterpolationTime = 0.1f;


    #region Values

    // I need to access this variables
    private bool _xPos, _yPos, _zPos, _xRot, _yRot, _zRot, _xSca, _ySca, _zSca;
    private bool xPos // I have already tried this, but it does not work
    {
        get { return _xPos; }
        set { _xPos = value; }
    } 

    #if UNITY_EDITOR

    [CustomEditor(typeof(PlayerNetwork))]
    public class Rotation : Editor
    {
        public override void OnInspectorGUI()
        {
            base.OnInspectorGUI();
            PlayerNetwork network = (PlayerNetwork)target;
            EditorFields(network);
        }
        private static void EditorFields(PlayerNetwork network)
        {
            PlayerNetwork original = new PlayerNetwork();

            EditorGUILayout.Space();
            EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Syncing", EditorStyles.boldLabel);

            EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
            
            EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Position", GUILayout.MaxWidth(122));

            // I must change the original "_xPos" and other variables, but I cannot get them in this void
            original.xPos = network._xPos = EditorGUILayout.Toggle(network._xPos, GUILayout.MaxWidth(14));
            EditorGUILayout.LabelField("X", GUILayout.MaxWidth(30));
            original._yPos = network._yPos = EditorGUILayout.Toggle(network._yPos, GUILayout.MaxWidth(14));
            EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Y", GUILayout.MaxWidth(30));
            original._zPos = network._zPos = EditorGUILayout.Toggle(network._zPos, GUILayout.MaxWidth(14));
            EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Z", GUILayout.MaxWidth(30));

            EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();

            EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();

            EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Rotation", GUILayout.MaxWidth(122));

            original._xRot = network._xRot = EditorGUILayout.Toggle(network._xRot, GUILayout.MaxWidth(14));
            EditorGUILayout.LabelField("X", GUILayout.MaxWidth(30));
            original._yRot = network._yRot = EditorGUILayout.Toggle(network._yRot, GUILayout.MaxWidth(14));
            EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Y", GUILayout.MaxWidth(30));
            original._zRot = network._zRot = EditorGUILayout.Toggle(network._zRot, GUILayout.MaxWidth(14));
            EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Z", GUILayout.MaxWidth(30));

            EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();

            EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();

            EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Scale", GUILayout.MaxWidth(122));

            original._zSca = network._xSca = EditorGUILayout.Toggle(network._xSca, GUILayout.MaxWidth(14));
            EditorGUILayout.LabelField("X", GUILayout.MaxWidth(30));
            original._zSca = network._ySca = EditorGUILayout.Toggle(network._ySca, GUILayout.MaxWidth(14));
            EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Y", GUILayout.MaxWidth(30));
            original._zSca = network._zSca = EditorGUILayout.Toggle(network._zSca, GUILayout.MaxWidth(14));
            EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Z", GUILayout.MaxWidth(30));

            EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
        }
    }

    #endif

    #endregion

    private void Update()
    {
        print("UPDATE X POSITION: " + xPos); // there should be true as I have selected it in Inspector
        if (IsOwner)
        {
            _netState.Value = new PlayerNetworkData()
            {
                Position = transform.position,
                Rotation = transform.rotation.eulerAngles
            };
        }
        else
        {
            transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp
                (transform.position, _netState.Value.Position, ref _vel, _cheapInterpolationTime);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, Mathf.SmoothDampAngle(transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y,
                _netState.Value.Rotation.y, ref _rotVel, _cheapInterpolationTime), 0);
        }
    }

    struct PlayerNetworkData : INetworkSerializable
    {
        private float _xPos, _zPos;
        private short _yRot;

        internal Vector3 Position
        {
            get => new Vector3(_xPos, 0, _zPos);
            set
            {
                _xPos = value.x;
                _zPos = value.z;
            }
        }
        internal Vector3 Rotation
        {
            get => new Vector3(0, _yRot, 0);
            set => _yRot = (short)value.y;
        }

        public void NetworkSerialize<T>(BufferSerializer<T> serializer) where T : IReaderWriter
        {
            serializer.SerializeValue(ref _xPos);
            serializer.SerializeValue(ref _zPos);

            serializer.SerializeValue(ref _yRot);
        }
    }
}
```

I am sorry if I have writen smth not correct, english isn't my native language. Thanks for help.

I have tried to do it with this, but it also does not work until I am bad in this kind of things

```
private bool xPos
    {
        get { return _xPos; }
        set { _xPos = value; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
PlayerNetwork original = new PlayerNetwork();
```

is a no-go for things derived from `MonoBehaviour`, it doesn't make any sense since a component can only exist as attached to a `GameObject`.

I'm also pretty sure you do **not** want to create new instances of your component at all - even less in a method that is called various times for each mouse movement and input events.

---

You rather want to assign those values only to the `network` instance you already have.

In general note though that this isn't really what `CustomEditor` is good for, usually you would rather serialize those fields and overwrite them via `SerializedProperty` so that they are handling Undo/Redo and dirty marking and finally serializing (=saving) those values persistent into your prefabs and scene assets.

Otherwise this will never work outside of the Unity Editor because once the app is built nobody can use your Custom Editor for setting those flags anymore ;)

---

So usually you would rather have e.g. (I will not do all of them - you will get the point)

```
[SerializeField] private bool _xPos;
[SerializeField] private bool _yPos;
[SerializeField] private bool _zPos;
```

and then in the editor

```
private SerializedProperty x;
private SerializedProperty y;
private SerializedProperty z;

private void OnEnable()
{
    // Link the fields
    x = serializedObject.FindProperty(nameof(_xPos));
    y = serializedObject.FindProperty(nameof(_xPos));
    z = serializedObject.FindProperty(nameof(_xPos));

    ....
}

public override void OnInspectorGUI()
{
    ...

    // Load current values 
    serializedObject.Update();

     EditorGUILayout.PrefixedLabel("Position");

   using(new EditorGUILayout.HorizontalScope())
   {
        EditorGUILayout.LabelField("x", GUILayout.Width(30));
        EditorGUILayout.PropertyFiled(x, GUIContent.None);
        EditorGUILayout.LabelField("y", GUILayout.Width(30));
        EditorGUILayout.PropertyFiled(y, GUIContent.None);
        EditorGUILayout.LabelField("z", GUILayout.Width(30));
        EditorGUILayout.PropertyFiled(z, GUIContent.None);
    }

    ...

    // apply values back
    serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
}
```

Question is if you need that custom inspector at all. You could as well stick to

```
[Header("Position")]
[SerializeField] private bool _xPos;
[SerializeField] private bool _yPos;
[SerializeField] private bool _zPos;
```

and not force them into horizontal..

Comment: Sure, but I just cannot do smth like that without `CustomEditor`.
I can't paste image.
I just wanted to do it so that it will look nice, in 3 awesome horizontal layers.

Comment: have to jump right now but I can get back later and do that .. is is basically what I showed in the middle but adding the horizontal layout groups again .. typing on the phone

Comment: thank you for your help, I guess I gonna try to do this tomorrow though

Comment: I have just tested your variant, but there is some mistake like "The name `serializedObject` does not exist in current context", did I miss smth?

Comment: [serializedObject](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Editor-serializedObject.html) is a property of the `Editor` class your custom editor inherits from .. so I don't really see why it should not exist